# MPC K-means constraints definiton using conclust package in R

Tags: r, k-means

I'm using the conclust package in R to perform semi-supervised clustering using MPC k-means algorithm to cluster fuel stations based on their activities.
I started with the code below.

```
mustLink =list(c ('station x','stations y'))
cantLink = list(c('station z','station w'))
mpckm(subset, 5, mustLink, cantLink, maxIter = 10)
```

subset is my dataframe.
stations x, stations y, station z and station w  represents the row index.

My problem is I'm not sure how to define my constraints.
For now I'm begining with simple constraints like for example I don't want station X to be in the same cluster with station Y.

In the conclust package, the mpckm function takes two lists of must-link and cannot-link constraints but no further details are added.

I tried to do the same thing adding the row index of the stations in the constraints lists. but this didn't work throwing this error:

> Error in 1:nm : argument of length 0.

What Am I exactly missing ?

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me working with objects of class `matrix`. Apart from the example of the help, matrices are also considered.

So you should do something similar to (assuming `dataset`is a `data.frame`):

```
mustLink =
cbind(which(rownames(subset)=='station x'),which(rownames(subset)=='stations y'))

cantLink =
cbind(which(rownames(subset)=='station z'),which(rownames(subset)=='station w'))

mpckm(subset, 5, mustLink, cantLink, maxIter = 10)
```